# No puedo sumar filas en datastudio, la suma da datos erroneos

Tags: google-data-studio

Estoy intentando sumar los valores de las filas en una tabla dinámica en data studio, si coloco un solo campo, me pone el valor correcto, pero si lo sumo con otro campo u otro número, el resultado es errado.

[image: Aquí tenemos un solo campo, y pone el valor correcto]

En la siguiente imagen, le sumo 2, y el resultado no es correcto.
¿cuál puede ser el error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando realizo multiplicaciones o divisiones, funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como solución parcial, logré que funcionara para algunas filas con:
SUM(campo)+SUM(campo)

Esto funcionó bien en algunos campos, inexplicablemente, no funciona en otros, tocó hacer el cálculo en la hoja de cálculo.